# Appending a pair of numpy arrays in a specific format to a 3rd array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm extracting data points in pairs from a data set. A pair consists of 2 numpy arrays, each shaped `(3, 30, 30)`. Let's call them `X1` and `Y1`.  The next pair will then be `X2` and `Y2`, followed by `X3` and `Y3`, etc.  I don't know how many pairs there will be in total, so I have to use something like `np.append`.

So I want something like:

```
>>X1, Y1 = extract_X_and_Y_from_data(data)
>>pair1 = np.array([X1, Y1])
>>pair1.shape
(2, 3, 30, 30)
>>list_of_pairs.some_append_function(pair1)
>>list_of_pairs.shape
(1, 2, 3, 30, 30)

>>X2, Y2 = extract_X_and_Y_from_data(data)
>>pair2 = np.array([X2, Y2])
>>list_of_pairs.some_append_function(pair2)
>>list_of_pairs.shape
(2, 2, 3, 30, 30)
```

...

```
>>X50, Y50 = extract_X_and_Y_from_data(data)
>>pair50 = np.array([X50, Y50])
>>list_of_pairs.some_append_function(pair50)
>>list_of_pairs.shape
(50, 2, 3, 30, 30)
```

All in all, I need the final list_of_pairs to be a numpy array of shape `(no_of_pairs, 2, 3, 30, 30)`. `np.append` keeps giving me `(no_of_pairs, 2)`, and I'm not too sure why.

Note: `np.concatenate`, `vstack` or `hstack` are tricky to implement because they can't seem to execute the first instance, i.e. appending the first pair to an initially empty `list_of_pairs`.

Thanks!

Comment: to use `hstack` and so on you just need to 'seed' with an empty array with the correct shape, like `(0, 2, 3, 30, 30)` in your case.

Comment: Start with an o/p array of shape : `(no_of_pairs, 2, 3, 30, 30)` and iteratively by indexing assign values into it. So, with the first pair : `out[0,0] = X1, out[0,1] = Y1`; second pair : `out[1,0] = X2, out[1,1] = Y2,` and so on.

Comment: @Divakar the number of pairs is not known in advance...

Comment: @JulienBernu Ah missed that point!

Comment: Also using `hstack` iteratively is expensive since you reallocate and copy every time. Better is to create and append on a native python list, and only at the end call `np.hstack` or any other stacking function. This also solves the problem of 'seeding'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With list append

```
list_of_pairs = []   # real list
for data in database:
    X1, Y1 = extract_X_and_Y_from_data(data)
    pair1 = np.array([X1, Y1])
    list_of_pairs.some_append_function(pair1)
array5d = np.array(list_of_pairs)
>> array5d.shape
(50, 2, 3, 30, 30)
```

`appending` to a list is relatively fast since it just adds a pointer to the list.  Your `pair` array remains in memory.

`np.array(alist)` builds a new array, joining the components on a new dimension (same as in `np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])`)

There is a new function `np.stack` that gives you a more control over which dimension is new.  All the `stack` functions end up calling `np.concatenate`.  That includes the misnamed (and oft misused) `np.append`.  `concatenate` requires matching dimensions (in the joining direction).  The various `stacks` just adjust the overall number of dimensions.